# Can you release binaries on GitHub, and have it under an EULA?

Tags: licensing, eula

Say someone made software, put it up on GitHub under the GPLv3 License, but then had an EULA that is not supplied with the binaries on GitHub, do you have to follow the EULA, or the GPL? And do they have to supply the source code with the binaries?

Comment: How do I know there is an eula when it is not distributed together?

Comment: Do you mean they put the source in the git repo and binaries on a Releases project tab? And the repo contains both the GPL and a EULA? And the git repo states that the binary (not present in the repo but attached to the project via Releases) is covered by the EULA despite the binary itself not containing the EULA? This is what I guess from your question text but each of these assumptions might be wrong -- could you clarify the situation? Also, are there multiple authors of the GPL'd code, or just one author of all GPL code involved?

Comment: The project is made by 4 authors, on the github there is just a license, a readme, and a releases tab which has only the binaries, not an eula or anything along with it. Theres a discord server linked in the readme which has an eula that says you cannot modify, sell, distribute the software and so on, but that goes against the GPLv3 in the github repo. I was wondering, if you decompiled the program, were you allowed to do that because of the gpl, or were you not because of the eula, that is on a discord server. Also, what if it was on the github repo, then do you have to follow the eula or gpl

Comment: Can you provide a link to the repository in question? Then we can take a fist-hand look at the situation.

Comment: https://github.com/MidasClient/Client-Releases
This is the repo, but for some reason the discord server is getting a revamp, and that ofcourse had to be right now

Comment: In general, there is nothing wrong with releasing your own source code under one license (e.g., the GPL) and a compiled form of your own code under a different license (e.g., a proprietary EULA), but that naturally does allow others to compile and distribute the GPL code. If there are multiple authors of GPL code, they must all agree to license it concurrently under GPL-incompatible terms. I haven't inspected the situation closely so I can't say how much of this general advice applies to this specific situation.

Comment: Having glaced at the repo, they really need to clarify what license(s) apply to what artifacts; any analysis about license compatibility I might offer would be based on guesswork about what licensing arrangement the authors intended by their confusing arrangement of license texts.

Comment: My impression is that the authors of that repo did not intend to release their work under the GPLv3 license, but they accidentally chose that one when creating an empty repo to host their releases.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly distribute code under GPL freely (e.g. via github) while selling licenses (EULAs) with additional rights (create closed derivatives, for instance) using other channels. You just have to make sure you have *all* rights to whatever you license separately (i.e., you have to get everybody who contributes changes to the public version write over the rights to you if you want to incorporate it into the EULAed package). This is usually called a CLA (Contributor Licence Agreement) to be formally accepted by any contributor before you integrate the contribution,